# I'm trying to build a chat bot using the Microsoft bot framework

Tags: javascript, node.js, botframework

I have defined a dictionary here

```
var dict = {'English 101?': 'Room 205', 'English 102?': 'Room 309',
  'Math 301': 'Room 705', 'Math 302': 'Room 704'};
```

I want the bot to reply "in Room 205" when the user ask "where is English 101".

I hardcoded it the following way:

```
var builder = require('botbuilder');
var helloBot = new builder.TextBot();
var dialog = new builder.CommandDialog();


dialog.matches('^Where is English 101?', builder.DialogAction.send('In     Room 205'));
dialog.matches('^Where is English 102?', builder.DialogAction.send('In     Room 309'));
dialog.matches('^Where is Math 301?', builder.DialogAction.send('In    Room 705'));
dialog.matches('^Where is Math 302?', builder.DialogAction.send('In     Room 704'));

dialog.onDefault(builder.DialogAction.send("I'm sorry. I didn't    understand."));

helloBot.listenStdin();
```

Instead of hardcoding each question  i want to pass some  Regular Expression to the dialog.matches() functions first parameter and using it as a key the Bot should be able to get value from the dictionary and send back to the user

I tried the following, but it didn't work:

```
var str = ""
dialog.matches(str = ? , builder.DialogAction.send(dict[str.slice(9)]))
```

How could I be able to pass standard input to "str" and get the value from dictionary?

Comment: please change your post title to reflect what you actually need help with.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use intents or trigger action matching.

For intents, first, initialize your intents:

```
var intents = new builder.IntentDialog();
```

Then pass the intent dialog to your bot:

```
bot.dialog('/', intents);
```

Then you can construct your matches using regular expressions:

```
intents.matches(/English 101/i, (session) => {
    //
});
```

You'll want to make sure to have something to handle messages with no matches too:

```
intents.onDefault([
    (session, args, next) => {
        //Do something by default
}]);
```

Another way would be to use a `triggerAction` on a dialog (which also uses regular expressions):

```
bot.dialog("/English", (sess, args, next) => {
        //Handle English 101
    }).triggerAction({
        matches: /English 101/i
});
```

With either, you'll be able to use standard JavaScript regular expressions to capture user data, and provide an appropriate dialog.

You can also look for just `/where is/i`, and then get the message from the session with `session.message.text`, and then parse that to get the target.

Ideally, your bot is well suited for using LUIS. You can create a single intent for the class location and a single entity for the class. Then you can train your LUIS app with various phrases, while replacing exact class names with the entity token. Then when LUIS hits your intent, the entity will be available, which you can use to access your dictionary and get the location. I [wrote a post](https://codepunk.io/adding-luis-to-your-bot-for-the-microsoft-bot-framework/) on this recently, if you're interested.

(Note: this is written in TypeScript, but you get the gist.)

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation [here](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/node/builder/chat/IntentDialog/) you should simply use Javascript regular expression format in your `matches` method.